# Fetch results from $start variable

Tags: doctrine-orm

Here is a simple query:

```
//...
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('
        SELECT r
        FROM AcmeGolferBundle:Golfer g
        LEFT JOIN g.shots r
        WHERE g.id = :id'
        )
            ->setParameter('id',$id);

return $query->getResult();
```

Is there a way to fetch the results from **`$start`** to **`$end`**? For example, if there are **50** results, is it possible to fetch the results from **`$start=20`** to **`$end=30`**?
I suppose I just have to do this to fetch a total of **10 objects**:

```
$query->setMaxResults(10);
```

### **But, how can I fetch all the results from the 20th result?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$query->setFirstResult(20);
```

Update:
See the [docs for DQL Query](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#first-and-max-result-items-dql-query-only).

Comment: Thanks @Tamas Imrei. The doc is pretty heavy and I missed that one :-) Cheers.